# What's the best way to persist information on session with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have a page that show the name of user after login, but, if a press F5 the page reloads and the name does not appear. How can I persist this information in the session?

Comment: This is a very broad question. What backend are you using? Is it a single page application or are you using cookies?

Comment: My backend is Java using JAX-RS. Not using cookies, but, thinking use sessionStorage or localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

Session Storage would be your first choice, take a look at the [`ngStorage`](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngStorage) module. I haven't tested it and it doesn't seem to be widely used but it's a good starting point even if you want to write your own implementation.

Though unless you have a good reason to go against cookies consider using the inbuilt [`$cookies`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/%24cookies) service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $cookieStore service. Docs can be found at [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/%24cookieStore)

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting modern browsers (i.e. IE8+), simply use `sessionStorage` if you only want the data to persist for the current session, or `localStorage` if you want the data to persist across multiple sessions. No need to use a third-party library. It's built in already.